# Create object from array of objects by dynamic properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects

```
  "options": [
    {
      "width": 10,
      "height": 20
    },
    {
      "width": 20,
      "height": 40
    },
    {
      "width": 30,
      "height": 60
    }
  ]
```

That I want convert to the following

```
{ width: [10, 20, 30], height: [20, 40, 60] }
```

Now keep in mind that the keys are dynamic. In this instance it's `width` and `height`.

I do actually have solution.

```
const pluck = (arr: Record<string, any> | undefined, property: string) => {
  return arr?.map((obj: any) => {
    return obj[property];
  });
};
const unique = (arr: any[] | undefined) =>
  arr ? Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...arr)) : null;

const keys = unique(myArray);
const options = keys
  ? Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key) => [key, pluck(myArray, key)]))
  : null;
```

But can I make this shorter?

Comment: Such a handsome code. why do you want to be shorter?

Comment: @Danial Thanks! I just have a feeling that it can be done better, maybe using reduce.

Comment: do not find the shorter because your app user doesn't care about it, find the most responsive code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is just to write a loop. Let's start with just JavaScript and then we'll come back to types:

```
const result = {};
for (const entry of myArray) {
    for (const key in entry) { // or: of Object.keys(entry)
        const values = result[key] = result[key] ?? [];
        values.push(entry[key]);
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const myArray = [
    {
        "width": 10,
        "height": 20
    },
    {
        "width": 20,
        "height": 40
    },
    {
        "width": 30,
        "height": 60
    }
];

const result = {};
for (const entry of myArray) {
    for (const key in entry) { // or: of Object.keys(entry)
        const values = result[key] = result[key] ?? [];
        values.push(entry[key]);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Re `for (const key in entry)` vs. `for (const key of Object.keys(entry)`, the former also visits inherited properties. Your example doesn't have any inherited properties, but if you had them, you could either add a `hasOwnProperty` check, or if you don't mind the temporary array, use `of Object.keys(entry)`.

Okay, so: Types. I was expecting this to be quite difficult, but it turned out not to be, which makes me suspicious I'm missing something. :-) We'd use a function for it so we can use type parameters:

```typescript
function condense<ObjType extends object>(array: ObjType[]) {
    const result: Record<string, any> = {};
    for (const entry of array) {
        for (const key in entry) { // or: of Object.keys(entry)
            const values = result[key] = result[key] ?? [];
            values.push(entry[key]);
        }
    }
    return result as {[key in keyof ObjType]: ObjType[key][]};
}
const result = condense(myArray);
console.log(result);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Since the result is built up over time, I used fairly loose types within the `condense` function, but the input and output are properly typed. For instance, the result of `result` above is `{ width: number[]; height: number[]; }`, which is what we want. It even works if we throw in a third property (say, `description`) of a different type (say, `string`), giving us `{ width: number[]; height: number[]; description: string[]; }`: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUEMEwLwwNoCwAUDKTAN7FnUwBEA7gJYAmUAFrQFwwCMADABoqNUrTYBTRgHM2ULjABMg4SNrNxEYCkYAHKI3Dza-AB5LaKmAF8hJMpTuqmrDtyW2RoidNnyALMqONGoaWrr6hty0SiYBFkE2lg6edM7s8gDMgSlikjJy3ABs2Z4hmtp6BmBGWSbF8dRWxAC6ANzExABmAK5gwBFgMKBg6pDiADwA8gBGAFYAKgg64jDiJlDiIxAwIHPi-QB8ABToaJjcMwtL4njNAJQUlsPQMCga3QA2UNwASvsgKGY42g2jAUgEMHQYAQBxwFCs7SCnQBMCOz1gmygKCwIE6kLOCAeyU8yJQqPRMAA1uIsIxBpjsUSYAB6Zk7FDcXEwS77KAAOmpCAgRwZhMsKQpADd0B9uho4W8IJ8oHhBc0Fe8vqqaeqAPy6-BtcWeaWyjR8nTdCBsEVgLEIbUIe6IlJNBKWN5QbooQaK5WQ7bkR0wOlUmlcy6LZbNC5zKM3NW3BHEN3ECl+r5w4ajCDiI6IVAYQmI54gD7iPkfEBSI4ZqB3RFAA)

---

The fad at present is to use `reduce`, but there's no reason to use it here, all it does is add complexity.

Comment: He said "keep in mind that the keys are dynamic."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hey T.J, is it possible to add TypeScript support?

Comment: @Unknown - Sorry, I cannot understand how I missed multiple fundamental things about your question (that the keys were dynamic, that you're using TypeScript). Both are blindingly clear and yet... I'll see if I can, but the types aspect of this is very complicated indeed. I may just need to delete the answer. But let me give it a try. :-)

Comment: @Unknown - Your current result is of type `{[k: string]: any} | null`. That's relatively easy to replicate, but I feel like I'd be cheating. :-) To actually have a typed result would require that the input array be `as const`, I think.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're a gem, nothing to apologize for. I used `Record<string, any> | null` but it still complains about this part `values.push(entry[key])`. "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type". I'll give it a try myself. Thanks!

Comment: @Unknown - Thanks! You're very kind given how badly I read the quesetion. :-) It turned out to be easier than I thought, and didn't require `as const`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i do with for loop, because its more responsive and faster than map or reduce.

```js
  const options = [
    { "width": 10, "height": 20 },
    { "width": 20, "height": 40 },
    { "width": 30, "height": 60 }
  ];
//That I want convert to the following
//{ width: [10, 20, 30], height: [20, 40, 60] }

let newobj = new Object();
for( let a of options ){
  for( let b of Object.keys(a) ){
    if( !newobj[b] ) newobj[b]=[]; newobj[b].push(a[b]);
  }
}
console.log(newobj)
```

Comment: *i do with for loop, because its more responsive and faster than map or reduce.* Speed/performance is not an issue at all. And therefore I recommend to get familiar with all array methods and with object iteration based on `Object[keys|values|entries]`. Such methods consume functions. Thus for more complex data-structures one can write reusable code for repetitive tasks like data-conversion and tree-walking. If such functions are also named in a precise and human readable way one does help other developers to more easily comprehend and maintain the code one once came up with.

Answer (score -1):

See [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for additional info.

```js
const input = [
  { width: 100, height: 100 },
  { width: 200, height: 200 },
  { width: 300, height: 300 },
];

const group = (someArrayOfObjects) => {
  return someArrayOfObjects.reduce((acc, current) => {
    Object.entries(current).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (!acc[key]) {
        acc[key] = [];
      }
      acc[key].push(value);
    });
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

console.log(group(input))
```

Comment: There's no reason for reduce here. Just a loop.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Out of curiosity, is there any particular reason why you'd recommend using a for loop? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: `reduce` is great when you're doing functional programming with predefined, reusable reducers. It's meh if you're at least changing the accumulator (for instance, summing an array). Beyond that, it's just a more complicated, harder to write, harder to read way to write a loop. (It's not just me, btw. :-) but also folks like [Jake Archibald](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224) and [Brian Terlson](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544), ...)

Comment: Haha, fair. Perhaps it is a fad. I've personally found `for` more complex and the separate `let` a little gross. That being said, the example you've given for this question is honestly . Thanks for the lesson in the power of `for`

Comment: Arman, people like you who listen (even when ending up not agreeing) rather than blindly reacting make SO a better place. Thanks! And happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

```js
var height = [], width = [];
options.forEach((op) =>{
  height.push(op.height)
  width.push(op.width)
})
   var returnValue = {width: width, height: height}
```

Comment: _"Now keep in mind that the keys are dynamic."_